# How to create custom non-linear tick marks on XYChart axis in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I need to put a completely custom set of non-linear tickmarks on an axis of an `XYChart`. Can you give me some general high-level advice on how to approach this? It doesn't seem to be supported directly by the API, unless I'm missing something.

Whether the points are actually plotted non-linearly along that axis doesn't matter to me, because I can distort the data before plotting it.

An easy option I've considered is setting the `tickLabelFormatter` property on the axis with a custom `StringConverter` subclass that distorts the number before converting it to a string. Even though this will result in correct labels, they will be very unround numbers. Ideally the ticks and gridlines should not be evenly spaced on the screen, but on their own non-linear scale's roundish numbers.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but you probably need to subclass `NumberAxis` and override `calculateTickValues` and `calculateMinorTickMarks`. You'll almost certainly need to browse through the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.java) (and, yes, in a really well-written API this wouldn't be necessary).

Comment: NumberAxis is final so you have to use ValueAxis<Number> . It's been done for [logarithmic values](http://blog.dooapp.com/2013/06/logarithmic-scale-strikes-back-in.html) and it's what I did for a time axis.